# Data across GUI, Matlab

Tags: matlab

So i tried to share GUI data using setappdata and getappadata. for example lets consider this

```
matfile1.m

h = EmotivEEG;
h.Run
for k = 1:4
   out(:,:,k) = h.data + rand(1);
   setappdata(0,'eegData', out(:,:,k);
   pause(0.5);
end
h.delete
```

so the above file creates a 128x14 matrix every o.5 seconds and store it in eegData

```
matfile2.m

some_var = getappdata(0,'eegData')
plot(some_var)
```

this seems to work but not while in the loop, if i ask it to plot it i get this error

```
Error using setappdata
Too many output arguments.
Error in eeg_live>eeg_live_OpeningFcn (line 83)
lmno = setappdata(0,'eegData');
Error in gui_mainfcn (line 221)
    feval(gui_State.gui_OpeningFcn, gui_hFigure, [], guidata(gui_hFigure), varargin{:});
Error in eeg_live (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
Error in Neucube>activation_Callback (line 3963)
eeg_live
Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
        feval(varargin{:});
Error in Neucube (line 49)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
Error in @(hObject,eventdata)Neucube('activation_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
Error using pause
Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

any idea on how to tackle this problem.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some problems with your code, but the line that MATLAB tells you generates the error is not in the snippet you provided, and the message is quite clear:

Using this command (line 83):

```
lmno = setappdata(0,'eegData');
```

is forbidden because `setappdata` does NOT accept output arguments, therefore the error is thrown. You can only use an assignment with `getappdata`.

Other points to consider:

1) Make sure you use the same variable name with `get/setappdata` (i.e. either `eegdata` or `eegData`...it might be a typo though)

2) You don't seem to call the 2nd script in your loop, so `setappdata` is overwriting the value of `eegData` at every iteration.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you. Typo. Its working great but i have one more question, what if i want to plot `out(:,:,k)` simultaneously ?

Comment: because if i plot once in one file (fig1) and open the second file (fig2), first file seems to pause and continue in the second one. is it possible to plot on both files at a time?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand; maybe you could create a figure with 2 subplots and alternatively create the plots? Look at the `Parent` property of axes; it allows you to select where you want to plot particular data.